# What do I use now that Obfuscated is not working in Kotlin or Java Code?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, android-r8, android-obfuscation

I try to obfuscate my project so that I enable a few settings in Gradle. then I try to reverse the code but not fully obfuscate

I refer many sites I did not find an exact solution yet

I try to decompile very famous apps like any google app & Facebook from the play store (code seems fully obfuscated).

can anyone give a suggestion of what should I do exactly to make **full code obfuscate**

- Below 3 Steps No use for code obfuscate

**Step 1:** Gradle Properties:

```
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=obsolete
android.enableR8.fullMode=true
```

**Step 2:** App level Gradle:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

**Step 3:** proguard-rules.pro
I also try proguard rules

```
# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

**Here is my kotlin code :**

```
package com.android.myapplication
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d("myTag","on create")
        try{
            val deviceInfo = " MOBILE: Android" +
                    " APP VERSION:" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME +
                    " MODEL:" + Build.MODEL +
                    " Manufacture:" + Build.MANUFACTURER +
                    " BRAND:" + Build.BRAND +
                    " SDK:" + Build.VERSION.SDK +
                    " OS: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE
            //Sets the text to be displayed.
            android_info.text =deviceInfo
        } catch (e: Exception){
            android_info.text =e.message
        }

    }
}
```

here I try to reverse code my release build.
**Android Apk decompiler:** http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

**Decompiler output:**

```
package com.android.myapplication;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.HashMap;
import p000a.p002b.p003c.C0034n;
import p082c.p083a.p084a.C0741a;

public final class MainActivity extends C0034n {

    /* renamed from: o */
    public HashMap f2788o;

    /* renamed from: o */
    public View mo2896o(int i) {
        if (this.f2788o == null) {
            this.f2788o = new HashMap();
        }
        View view = (View) this.f2788o.get(Integer.valueOf(i));
        if (view != null) {
            return view;
        }
        View findViewById = findViewById(i);
        this.f2788o.put(Integer.valueOf(i), findViewById);
        return findViewById;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("myTag", "on create");
        try {
            TextView textView = (TextView) mo2896o(R.id.android_info);
            C0741a.m1859a(textView, "android_info");
            textView.setText(" MOBILE: Android APP VERSION:1.0 MODEL:" + Build.MODEL + " Manufacture:" + Build.MANUFACTURER + " BRAND:" + Build.BRAND + " SDK:" + Build.VERSION.SDK + " OS: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) mo2896o(R.id.android_info);
            C0741a.m1859a(textView2, "android_info");
            textView2.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes:**
After enabling the above Gradle setting:

- App size is reduced 40%
- It also removed unused classes & res files in my project.

Comment: Please do not use `useProguard true`. That setting has been deprecated, and I am not sure exactly what it does right now. With just `minifyEnabled true` R8 will be used to shrink, and with `android.enableR8.fullMode=true` the most aggressive shrinking will be used. You can also experiment with `-repackageclasses` to move to the root package. If you see a class/method which is not obfuscated, you can use the `-whyareyoukeeping` to see what keep rule is being used for that item.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to obfuscate 100%, because the entry-points would get lost. For example, if you'd obfuscate `MainActivity`, then the reference in the `AndroidManifest.xml` would become invalid and you couldn't launch it anymore. This is working as intended, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: thank u for a response, I disable all below-grade setting, getting the same output when I decompile.
I try to decompile very famous app like transit, miles,.. but the code fully obfuscated, I can not find the class name itself. (i think they are uploading some mapping file)

(minifyEnabled false/
shrinkResources false/
kotlin.code.style=official/
android.enableR8.fullMode=false)

Comment: They do nothing else, else their applications wouldn't run either ...people usually have far more of a problem when obfuscating too much (which may break the application) and not too little. The mapping file is only good for Crashlytics, but is obviously not installed on any end-device. There's even a whole lot more classes, member variables and alike which one must not obfuscate. `Serializable` might be another good example. So how would you use it when it's obfuscated?